# sqlalchemy - select records by month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, select, sqlalchemy

when i have a table in MySQL:

```
create table t
(
    id integer primary key,
    time datetime not null,
    value integer not null
)
```

and an mapping class:

```
class T(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't'

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    time = Column(DATETIME, nullable=False)
    value = Column(INTEGER, nullable=False)
```

how can i select all values that have given month from this table using SQLAlchemy?
MySQL has the `month` function: `select value from t where month(time) = 4`
but SQLAlchemy has no `month` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without loading all `T`s into the session, one can use [Functions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#functions) to filter non April objects straight-away:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
qry = session.query(T).filter(func.MONTH(T.time) == 4)
for t in qry:
    print t.value
```

Comment: Does this work for all databases though? I don't think postgresql for example supports the month scalar. I think a func is the right idea here, but it seems to me that `func.date_part('month', T.time)`  is a better way to go about it.

Comment: You are right, this is RDBMS-specific. The question is tagged with `mysql`, so the sample code was such that it works there.

Answer (score 3):

A very old question but a better answer is here:

```
from sqlalchemy import extract  

session.query(T).filter(extract('month', T.time)==7).all()
```

This will return all the records into a database in July.

Answer (score 1):

If for example you want the records from all April months irrespective of year or day:

```
for t in session.query(T):
    if t.time.month == 4: print t.value
```